# create a block `catalog/product_list` with custom products ids

Tags: php, magento

i have some products ids in a $ids and i want to render them in magneto default catalog/product_list block,

```
echo $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('catalog/product_list', '', 
                    array(
                        'template'=> 'catalog/product/list.phtml' ,
                         "product_id" => $ids)
                )->toHtml();
```

this is not working either

```
echo $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('catalog/product_list', '', 
                    array(
                        'template'=> 'catalog/product/list.phtml' ,
                         "product_id" => $ids)
                )->setProductId($ids)->toHtml();
```

in other words i want the code version of this block

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" product_id="1,2,3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you could try instantiating the block and giving it a product collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addIdFilter([1, 2, 3]);

$block = $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
    ->setCollection($collection);

echo $block->toHtml();
```